# JRuby 1.6.1 string function in 1.9 mode

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails

I have just upgraded to jruby 1.6.1 and when I run in 1.9 mode, the following function fails when it encounters certain charaters.  The job of the function is to strip out unwanted characters and also leading and trailing characters.  I am adding the following function to the string class:

```
class String
  def strip_noise()
    return if empty? 
    self.force_encoding('utf-8').mb_chars.normalize(:kd).gsub(/[^\x00-\x7F]/n,'').to_s().strip()
  end
end
```

I have the following test that causes the error to happen:

```
  def test_odd_characters()
    assert_equal("", "        \xC2\xA0".strip_noise())
  end
```

I get a Java::JavaLang::NegativeArraySizeException: when I run the test.

Is this a bug with jruby or can anyone help me out with a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am fairly sure this is a jruby bug as it works in normal ruby 1.9.2, I have created the following [jira](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-5846).